# How to prevent my queries from getting out of order when I show them in the template with a nested loop

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am making a query to the database, ordering it by date and then sending it to the template, but it is displayed out of order in the template. I think the problem is the nested loop. When i take out the nested loop it worked but i really need the loop to be there. How can I make it work?

This is the query from the view:

recibos=grupo.recibos.all().order_by('-fecha_pago')

This is the template code:

```
{% if recibos %}
    <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-sm table-hover datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Responsable</th>
                <th class="text-center">Fecha</th>
                <th class="text-center">Monto</th>
                <th class="text-center">Forma de Pago</th>
                <th class="text-center"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for recibo in recibos %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>{{recibo.responsable.nombre}} {{recibo.responsable.apellido}}</div>
                        <div class="small"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa-solid fa-graduation-cap"></i></span>
                            {% for alumno in recibo.alumnos.all %}
                                {% if not forloop.last %}
                                    {{alumno.nombre}},
                                {% else %}
                                    {{alumno.nombre}}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <div>{{recibo.fecha_pago}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <div>${{recibo.importe|floatformat:"2g"}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <div>{{recibo.forma_pago}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <div>botones</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% else %}
    <br>
    {% if filtro == True %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center">
            <strong>No hay resultados para este filtro</strong>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center">
            <strong>No hay recibos para esta familia</strong>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I add the models below

```
class Alumno(models.Model):

    TIPOS_DE_DOCUMENTOS =(
        ("DNI", "DNI"),
        ("PASAPORTE", "Pasaporte"),
    )

    HISTORICO=(
        (False, "Activo"),
        (True, "Histórico"),
    )


    responsable_admin=models.ForeignKey('ResponsableAdmin', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='alumnos')
    cursos=models.ForeignKey('Curso', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='alumnos')  #no permitir null ni blank
    seccion=models.ForeignKey('Seccion', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='alumnos') #no permitir null ni blank
    turno=models.ForeignKey('Turno', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='alumnos') #no permitir null ni blank
    grupo=models.ForeignKey('Grupo', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='alumnos')
    instituto=models.ForeignKey('Instituto', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tipo_doc = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices = TIPOS_DE_DOCUMENTOS, default='DNI')
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    nombre_sin_tildes=models.CharField(max_length=70, default="")
    apellido=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    apellido_sin_tildes=models.CharField(max_length=60, default="")
    nombre_completo=models.CharField(max_length=140, default="")
    email=models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True )
    nro_doc=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True )
    nacionalidad=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True )
    domicilio=models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True )
    localidad=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True )
    cp=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True )
    telefono=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True )
    fecha_nac=models.DateField( blank=True, null=True )                            
    facturado=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    actual=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    proximo=models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    historico=models.BooleanField(choices=HISTORICO, default=False) 
    deudor=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Recibo(models.Model):

    FORMA_PAGO =(
        
        ("CONTADO", "Contado"),
        ("CREDITO", "Credito"),
        ("TRANSFERENCIA", "Transferencia"),
        ("CHEQUE", "Cheque"),
        ("DEBITO", "Debito"),
        ("MERCADO PAGO", "Mercado Pago"),
        ("RAPIPAGO", "Rapipago"),
        ("PAGO MIS CUENTAS", "Pago mis Cuentas"),

    )

    grupo=models.ForeignKey('Grupo', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='recibos')
    responsable=models.ForeignKey('ResponsableAdmin', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='recibos')
    alumnos=models.ManyToManyField('Alumno', related_name='recibos')
    factura=models.ManyToManyField('Factura', related_name="recibo")
    instituto=models.ForeignKey('Instituto', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    nro_recibo=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fecha_pago=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    importe=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    saldo_a_favor_usado=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    saldo_a_favor_restante=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    forma_pago=models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=FORMA_PAGO, default="Contado")
    facturas=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    anulado=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    es_debito=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    excedente=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    observaciones=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cae=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_vencimiento=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    es_credito=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    aplica_credito=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tarjeta=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    pv=models.CharField(max_length=2)
    venc_pronto=models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    descuento_pronto=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is the view
https://replit.com/@santiDedos/views#main.py

Comment: Is it the `alumnos` records that are not sorted? [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort) might help if you want to sort them in the template file.

Comment: You have ordered in descending order in the queryset, do you mean it shows template in ascending order?

Comment: Please share the model and the view.

Comment: Deniz Kaplan, thanks for answering. I tried dicsort and it didn't work, the query is still out of order.

Comment: Sunderam Dubey, thanks for answering. The query is displayed out of order. Neither ascending nor descending.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Van Onsem, thanks for answering. I uploaded the models and the view. I did not put the methods of the models to not put so much code. If necessary I upload them. Something that happened to me is that, when taking out this loop, {% for alumno in recibo.alumnos.all %}, the query was displayed in order.